# How to use s3upload to upload file directly without form?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm using s3upload to upload image using admin form. How can I avoid using form for uploading (selecting file through explorer) and upload file using some method (like upload("filename.jpg"))? Is it possible?

**options.py**

```
CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = {
    'image_field': ['django.forms.CharField', {
        'widget': 'myapp.apps.S3UploadWidget',
        'widget_kwargs': {'dest': 'options'},
        'required': False
    }],
```

s3upload library's **views.py**, which has upload logic:
https://github.com/yunojuno/django-s3-upload/blob/master/s3upload/views.py

Comment: Post the code that is uploading file from explorer?

Comment: Added, it's using django constance and s3upload library's views.py

Comment: In that case, take a look at the boto3 docs for s3.upload_file: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file